# UPS 30 AMP 240V question

Tags: 240v, neutral, ups

Okay here is what I am trying to accomplish.

I have a computer rack in my basement and since I am an IT guy to the extreme it has a lot of servers in it.  I have a UPS 240V 6000KVA unit.  It is rack mounted at the bottom of the computer rack.  The output has 5 X L6-30 connectors on it.  I also have some super nice PDUs in this rack that are also 240V.  However the input to them is a L21-30P plug type -  I opened this up as my first thought was this might be a 3 phase PDU, however the plug looked custom made so I took the connector apart to have a look at what the wiring was inside of one of them.

Inside It has Green in the Center for the Ground, White for Neutral, Black for Hot-1, Red for Hot-2 and that is it.  There is a nothing attached to the 5th plug and no other wires in the wire sleve.  If it was 3 phase I would have expected a Blue there as well for the 3rd hot wire.

So - what I would like to do it hook the UPS to the PDU - However, there is no Neutral output from the PDU as the outputs are all L6-30 which have three wires - Hot1, Hot2 and Ground no neutral.

so I can run the output into a juntion box and break it apart and add a neutral from another panel?  or is this a no no?  The reason for the neutral would be the display and management interface that reads out the load must use 120V hence the neutral.  That is not documented anywhere though but just my thoughts on why it has the connector it does -  although they could have used an L14-30 which would have been a better option as my first thought was this damn thing is 3 phase but that is not the case and It is hooked up today running 240V just fine - just without a UPS backup when the power goes out.

Any thoughts, suggestions or laughter is welcome[image]

Cheers

Comment: Yeah, that's weird, that socket is intended for 120/208V.  Well, change it to a NEMA 14-30 type.

Comment: They say the neutral has to be a part of same circuit loop

Comment: I agree on the NEMA 14-30  it is always interesting to get thrown a curve ball now and then.  These PDUs came out of a Data Center -  I am thinking some bozo had some left over NEMA  L21-30 Plugs and just used them.  I got them for free so I cannot complain as they are really nice.  When you consider how much things cost $100 for the right plug would have been the way to go back whenever that was.